# Google Bucket - Get a specific file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently working with Google Buckets and I am having a little trouble getting a specific file.

I am currently able to get all files by doing the following:

```
const [files] = await bucket.getFiles();
```

However, I am a little confused on how to get a single file, for example, if the name of the file in the bucket is "mypicture.jpg", do I use a prefix? Or do I use .file()?

```
const [file] = await bucket.getFiles({prefix: "mypicture.jpg"});
```

or

```
const [file] = await bucket.file("mypicture.jpg");
```

Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file function can be used to access a file reference

```
const file = await bucket.file("mypicture.jpg");
```

[reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-file-link-from-google-cloud-storage-using-node-js/)

Comment: Thanks for your response! 
Could I just confirm that this means I can use the file function to access an existing file in the bucket? 
The documentation mentions that it is used to create a new file.